# Which one to use Iteration or Recursion and Why?

Tags: recursion, iteration

Sorry I could not get an exact answer from other related questions here.In general, if we do not know beforehand how many iterations or repetitions we may need for a problem . Which would be a better solution in most of the cases and Why?

Comment: https://csc.cdf.toronto.edu/mybb/showthread.php?tid=1456

Answer (score 0):

I think this decision depends on the problem itself. If I had no idea about the number of iterations of the algorithm, I would use recursive algorithms when I feel that the nature of the problem helps me do that.

For example, if I wanted to calculate all possible non empty subsets from a given set, I would use a recursive algorithm, and if I wanted to calculate the sum of a list of elements, I would use an iterative algorithm.

In both cases I could use the other method to solve the problem, but I feel more comfortable coding this way.

Answer (score 0):

In programming languages that don't offer tail call elimination, then you should normally favor iteration over recursion for performance reasons. However, there are still some situations where a recursive solution is more intuitive and easier to type in. For example, solving problems that are recursive in nature (working with trees, backtracking, etc). In general, you should choose the most readable solution of the two options, and when performance matters, use the faster one, which is iteration.It is important to note that some languages don't provide looping capabilities, like Haskell. However, Haskell has tail call elimination, so when you want a loop, you could just write a tail recursive algorithm, and it will be translated into a loop by the compiler. So, recursion is not always necessarily slower than iteration as some people think.